# how can i Pass element values 'val[]' from parent window to child layer window element 'sel_value' for each corresponding click?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

her this DIV is the new layer window with one form.
showModal('modal') is a simple java script to hide/show new layer window

```
<div id="modal" style="border:3px solid black; background-color:#9999ff; padding:25px; font-size:150%; text-align:center; display:none;">
This is a hidden layer(only show after click)
<form name="frm" method=post action="">
Your name<input type="text" id="sel_value" name="sel_value" size=12 value=test> 
<input type=submit value='Submit' >
</form>
</div>
```

this is the parent window

```
<input type="text" name="va[]" id="va[]" size=12 value="2"><a href="#" onClick="Popup.showModal('modal');return false;">link</a>
<input type="text" name="va[]" id="va[]" size=12 value="3"><a href="#" onClick="Popup.showModal('modal');return false;">link</a>
<input type="text" name="va[]" id="va[]" size=12 value="4"><a href="#" onClick="Popup.showModal('modal');return false;">link</a>
<input type="text" name="va[]" id="va[]" size=12 value="5"><a href="#" onClick="Popup.showModal('modal');return false;">link</a>
<input type="text" name="va[]" id="va[]" size=12 value="6"><a href="#" onClick="Popup.showModal('modal');return false;">link</a>
```

.
.
.

Comment: The question is quite unclear. What are the "element values 'val[]'"? What is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: (complete change of answer according to the new info provided)

here is the script that should do what you want:

```
<html><head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

function modal(id){
  var txt=document.getElementById(id).innerHTML; //will copy the contents from the comment
  var x=window.open('','name','height=400,width=500'); 
    x.document.write('<form name="frm" method="post" action="">'); 
    x.document.write('Your name: <input type="text" id="sel_value" name="sel_value"><br />');
    x.document.write('<textarea>'+txt+"\nYour comment:\n"+'</textarea><br />');
    x.document.write('<input type="submit" value="Submit">');
    x.document.write('</form>');
}

</script>

</head><body>

<div id='va1'>comment 1</div><a href="#" onClick="modal('va1');">link 1</a>
<div id='va2'>comment 2</div><a href="#" onClick="modal('va2');">link 2</a>
<div id='va3'>comment 3</div><a href="#" onClick="modal('va3');">link 3</a>
<div id='va4'>comment 4</div><a href="#" onClick="modal('va4');">link 4</a>
<div id='va5'>comment 5</div><a href="#" onClick="modal('va5');">link 5</a>

</body></html>
```

Comment: @Riju you can edit the existing question to add the extra details. Creating a new question is frowned upon.

Comment: Riju, your new question is still unclear, you need to explain what you need? why are the input boxes needed? if this is a popup that you need, then the simplest way would be to have it on a different php/html file and load using of example this JS function: function popup(url) { window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150'); }

Comment: ok.. i have an array of comments from DB and each comment have a reply links. when i click on the anchor reply i need to open a new layer window.. and i need that particular comment id in the newly popup layer window..

Comment: @Riju, i have updated my answer! please check it, this should be the correct response. I have checked the script and it does work fine. With some additional addings/changes should be fine!

Comment: thanks i tried this but it open in a new window..i need to be this in the layer window not in the separate page.. can u help me

Comment: on your question: "a simple java script to hide/show new layer window" this is what it does opens a new window. if you need this to be on a layer. you would just need to create a div and use instead of x.document.write : document.getElementById('divid').innerHtml. the rest should be the same